# Exiting a function that has an event listener in it

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I'm still a bit new to web development, and I'm working on a project using HTML and JavaScript. Here is the problem I'm encountering.

```
<body>
    
<h1>random heading</h1>
<button id="clickme">clickme</button>

<p id="yes"></p>
<p id="no"></p>

<script>
    const clickme = document.querySelector('#clickme')
    const yes = document.querySelector('#yes')
    const no = document.querySelector('#no')

    let yesScore = 0;
    let noScore = 0;
    
    function game() {
        clickme.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

        function myFunction(){
            let promptVar = prompt('y/n');

            if(promptVar === 'y') yes.textContent = ++yesScore;
            else if(promptVar === 'n') no.textContent = ++noScore;
            else return;

            if(yesScore + noScore === 5){
                console.log('over');
            }
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
```

So my problem here is that I would like for the game() function to be exited when (yesScore + noScore === 5), but if I use return or break in the if statement, it only exits the myFunction() function.

I've tried using a label to jump out of the function directly after the console.log('over') to the outside of the game() function, only to learn that a label can't jump across function boundaries.

Comment: Where is the `game()` function called? You do realise that `myFunction` only runs when the user interacts by clicking the `#clickme` element

Comment: return a promise from `game` that is resolved only when the relevant condition is met - then you can `await` or `game().then` to achieve the result you want

Comment: I think you are not called `game()` function. Please try call it like `<body onload="game()">...</body>`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to delete the onclick event whenever the game ends You can use removeEventListener in this example. So here is the code :

```
<body>
    
<h1>random heading</h1>
<button id="clickme">clickme</button>

<p id="yes"></p>
<p id="no"></p>

<script>
    const clickme = document.querySelector('#clickme')
    const yes = document.querySelector('#yes')
    const no = document.querySelector('#no')

    let yesScore = 0;
    let noScore = 0;
    
    function game() {
        clickme.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

        function myFunction(){
            let promptVar = prompt('y/n');

            if(promptVar === 'y') yes.textContent = ++yesScore;
            else if(promptVar === 'n') no.textContent = ++noScore;
            else return;

            if(yesScore + noScore === 5){
                console.log('over');
                clickme.removeEventListener("click",myFunction);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
```

and here you will not need to get out of any function cause the click event is destroyed and if you hit click me it will not raise the event.
And note that when you get out of myFunction it will not go to game() function cause its an event. Because the function will be called whenever you click the buttuon.
Hope it had been useful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've used your method and it's working perfectly!

Answer (score -3):

You could do a pause inside of game function after myFunction.
That will pause that thread and nothing after it may run after it. If you really want to have game() end after that condition, do create Promise, have myFunction registerred with in addition to console.log, that Promise.resolve, and after that and myFunction, use await keyword to wait for that Promise to resolve, then after that do as you wish with game() not ended yet. There may be an await async like thing that can let code after it run before it is done waiting. Also, I suggest having myFunction before addEventListener. === is exact equals, I suggest using ==. You could also have an end function instead of ending in game(). You may remove an event listener inside an event listener. Like someView.removeEventListener(this);.

I find trying to end by being inside game() to be hard and with better alternatives. game() has all functions return immediately so if you want to end with game(), try initial game(initial=true) then setTimeout or setInterval with a time and a function calling game with initial = false like game(false) and if initial, set event listener, check for end condition, then if not end condition, setTimeout, or continue with intervals, but if end condition no new timeout, clearInterval with function passed to it, one or other.

With if end condition, then do what you would to end. setTimeout and setInterval allow code after them to run before end. Like this:

```js
function inter() {game(false)}

function game(initial=true) {
    if (initial) {
        //Starting code
    }
    if (end condition) {
        //End
    } else {
        setTimeout(inter, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: At best this answer is stream-of-conscious jottings, and honestly - the "X E" stuff is not illuminating at all, please stop adding it. No-one here knows what it means. I am not sure Stack Overflow is the right outlet for your material, to be honest.